# Groovy - how to init a value in map in maps with another value

Tags: dictionary, groovy

How to init a value in a map in maps with another value. i.e.

```
def my_map= ['key1': [ 'key2' : ['key3a' : 'x', 'key3b' : **'x'**]]]
```

I want to init the value of 'key3b' with the **same** value of 'key3a' (without specify 'x' again, but using the fit variable. I tried:

```
def my_map= ['key1': [ 'key2' : ['key3a' : 'x', 'key3b' :**"${my_map['key1']['key2']['key3a']}"** ]]]
```

but I get an error: **hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: my_map for class: WorkflowScript**

so, any ideas how to do it in Groovy?

Comment: Why not declare a variable before that and use it for both keys? `def x='x'; ...'key3a':x,'key3b':x...`?

Comment: because the value is related only to the inner map, and it will 'dirt' the code if it's outside the map

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't because `my_map` is only "there" once all the
literal for the map is done.  The easiest way out here usually is to
prepare the value for x first, and then do two assignments for your two
keys.

But if you really want to assign from a different existing key in the
literal, you can use e.g. `tap`:

```
def my_map= ['key1': [ 'key2' : ['key3a' : 'x']]].tap{
    key1.key2.key3b = key1.key2.key3a
}
assert my_map.key1.key2.key3b=='x'
```

(If you really want to golf this even further, you can even `tap` again
for the assignment)